# Visual Studio not letting me use sqrt or floor, ambiguous call to overloaded function

Tags: c++, sqrt

I have a call to

```
long long a = sqrt(n/2);
```

Both `a` and `n` are `long long`'s but it won't let me compile because it says my use of `sqrt()` is an ambiguous call. I don't see how it's possibly ambiguous here at all. How do I resolve this? I have the same problem with `floor()`.

My includes

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
```

Comment: Try casting the `n/2` to `double`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are several overloads of `sqrt()` and `floor()`, there's no "best match" for a call to `sqrt(long long)` according to the overload resolution rules. Just cast the argument to the appropriate type -- i.e.,

```
long long a = sqrt(static_cast<double>(n/2));
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//use 
sqrt(static_cast<double>(n/2));
//instead of 
sqrt(n/2);
```

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph Kinderkram and also unconsistent unfair with other answers

Comment: @Stefan Not Kinderkram, it’s a substantial percentage of the whole answer, as well as being *the central point*. As for being inconsistent, I *try* to be consistent, and I will downvote any answer which, as its central point, advocates a practice which I oppose.

Comment: @MaziarBouali C++. And the question is tagged C++. The C library you’re thinking of is `math.h`.

Comment: @MaziarBouali, the C header is `math.h`. The C++ one is `cmath`. The prominent difference is that one is part of the std namespace.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, To be fair, I think he means that Ernest's answer used a C-style cast too, before it got changed.

Comment: @MaziarBouali Totally irrelevant. Besides the fact that this reference is outdated and contains errors, *this code* is clearly C++. What language the library is written in is irrelevant. And even if it weren’t, §26.8 of the C++ standard includes this library.

Comment: @KonradRudolph, Oh, I thought it didn't have any when I checked. Maybe you did it right after :p

Comment: @MaziarBouali: note that if you changed `(double)` to `static_cast<double>()` form and pinged Konrad about it I am pretty sure he would remove his downvote. Downvotes on SO are (generally) not ad-hominem attacks, and most pave the way to a better answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `sqrt` functions expects a `float`, a `double` or a `long double`:

```
long long a = sqrt(n * 0.5);
```

You may lose some *precision* converting a `long long` to a `double`, but the value will be very close.

Comment: I don't understand why I need to change it to a double? Won't I lose accuracy/possibly truncate my variable? My n variable is quite large

Comment: @AgainstASicilian Well, there simply is no version for `long long`.

Comment: Oh, I wasn't aware of that. For which datatypes does sqrt() and floor() exist? Int and double?

Comment: @AgainstASicilian These functions have overloads for `float`, `double`, and `long double`. Since there's no version for `long long` the compiler has to convert your `long long` to one of those other types. Since all those conversions are equally good the compiler can't choose any one over the others and the call is ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

According to the reference

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cmath/sqrt/

I would propose to convert to **long double** first. 
No overload of **sqrt** accepts an integral value

integral parameter could always result in a "real" value (float, double, long double)